# Grant permissions in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, permissions, passwords

I'm trying to create a secure remote API for working with a database. Without having to create my own server daemon, I figured the best way would be using stored procedures.

My only problem is permissions. I want these procedures to be able to do things like make new users with passwords. I'm able to grant permission, but `INDENTIFIED BY` always wants a `TEXT_STRING` to come after it, so variables aren't allowed.

How can I allow my procedures to set passwords when granting permissions? I'd like to avoid creating a server daemon or modifying `mysql.user` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a prepared statement.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(param VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = CONCAT('GRANT ... ON ... TO ... IDENTIFIED BY ''', param, ''';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @cmd;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```